# How to Change Title Kerning Value of NavigationBar in iOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, kerning

I'm trying to adjust the kerning for the title text in the NavigationBar. I've gotten as far as assigning a custom **UIStringAttributes** to the NavigationBar title. Setting the font and the text color seems to work fine, but when I input the Kerning Adjustment, nothing happens, regardless of what value I input.

```
public void SetTitleFont (string fontName, float fontSize, Color foregroundColor)
{
    var TitleAttr = new UIStringAttributes {
        ForegroundColor = foregroundColor.ToUIColor(),
        Font = UIFont.FromName (fontName, fontSize),
        KerningAdjustment = 50
    }; 

    this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = TitleAttr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this one out.
What worked out for me was creating a new UILabel, set the attributes for the UILabel, then set the TitleView to the UILabel.

```
// We will grab the actual title of the Page further down.    
string viewTitle = string.Empty;

UINavigationItem navItem = new UINavigationItem();

if (this.NavigationController != null)
{
    if (this.NavigationController.VisibleViewController != null)
    {
        if (this.NavigationController.VisibleViewController.NavigationItem != null)
        {
            navItem = this.NavigationController.VisibleViewController.NavigationItem;

            // Grab the title of the Page you are on.
            if (navItem.Title != null)
            {
                viewTitle = this.NavigationController.VisibleViewController.NavigationItem.Title;
            }
        }
    }
}

// We do not want to set an arbitrary size for the UILabel.
// Otherwise, positioning it will be very difficult.
// The StringSize function will set the size of the UILabel to the absolute
// minimum size of whatever string you specify - given the correct
// parameters (font and fontSize).
CGSize titleSize = viewTitle.StringSize(UIFont.FromName (fontName, size));

// Create the new title UILabel. Make sure to set the Bounds!
pageTitleView = new UILabel {
    Bounds = new CGRect (0, 0, titleSize.Width, titleSize.Height),
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0)
};

var titleAttributes = new NSAttributedString (viewTitle,
    new UIStringAttributes () {
    ForegroundColor =  foregroundColor.ToUIColor(),
    Font = UIFont.FromName (fontName, size),
    KerningAdjustment = 1.1f
});

// Apply the new attributes to the UILabel and center the text.
pageTitleView.AttributedText = titleAttributes;
pageTitleView.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

// Set the TitleView to the new UILabel.
navItem.TitleView = pageTitleView;
```

I hope this helps!